# CSS boxes problems

Tags: html, css

I've created this box model and I want three more same boxes in column.

The CSS:

```
#box { 

}

#box .circle
{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:120px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
    left:75px;
    top:95px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#box .box1 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    width:270px;
    height:130px;
    top:160px;
    left:1px;
    background-color:black;
    padding:70px 40px 15px 40px;
    position:absolute;   
}

#box .box2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    width:270px;
    height:250px;
    top:280;
    left:1px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:70px 40px 15px 40px;
    position:absolute;
}

#box .box3 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    width:270px;
    height:70px;
    top:530px;
    left:1px;
    background-color:black;
    padding:70px 40px 15px 40px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And the markup:

```
    <body> 
    <div id="box">
         <div class="circle">10GB</div>
         <div class="box1"></div>
         <div class="box2"></div>
         <div class="box3"></div>
    </div>
    </form> 
    </body>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your `<form>` ?

Comment: mate can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: say more, what exactly you need ?

Comment: _"I want three more same boxes in column"_ Explain.

Comment: I wanna three same form boxes :(

like this http://s17.postimg.org/tkwx45ohb/bbbb.png

Comment: That's not an explanation, that's just repeating what you already said; and people didn't understand you the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all;

- You shouldn't use "position:absolute" as you can.
- Use "float:left" for combining vertical aligned elements.
- Use a "clearfix" solution (like http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) for clearing "float:left" overflowing.

Here is the solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    /* +++++ clearfix +++++ */

    .clearfix:after         { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
    .clearfix               { display: inline-block; }
    html[xmlns] .clearfix   { display: block; }
    * html .clearfix        { height: 1%; }

    /* ---- clearfix ---- */

.box { 
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width:270px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box .circleWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.box .circle
{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:120px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box .box1 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    height:120px;
}

.box .box2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    height:250px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:10px;
}

.box .box3 {
    height:60px;
}
.box .blackBoxCommon {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    padding:10px;
    background-color:black;
}
    </style>
</head>
    <body> 
        <form class="clearfix" action="#">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circleWrapper">
                    <div class="circle">10GB</div>
                </div>
                 <div class="box1 blackBoxCommon"></div>
                 <div class="box2"></div>
                 <div class="box3 blackBoxCommon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circleWrapper">
                    <div class="circle">10GB</div>
                </div>
                 <div class="box1 blackBoxCommon"></div>
                 <div class="box2"></div>
                 <div class="box3 blackBoxCommon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circleWrapper">
                    <div class="circle">10GB</div>
                </div>
                 <div class="box1 blackBoxCommon"></div>
                 <div class="box2"></div>
                 <div class="box3 blackBoxCommon"></div>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The one thing i dont like about your answer is using floats. i would use Display: inline-block. Its way better imo.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid absolute positions for main layout elements as boxes, wrappers, etc. The solution for you shoul be learn how to float elements correctly.

First read about the [CSS float property and clearfix](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) and after that this [demo](http://andrestorres.com.ar/junk/clearfix.html) should be easy a nice template to work on.

Comment: I've small time. if you help me it will be great :(

Comment: Then just use the [demo](http://andrestorres.com.ar/junk/clearfix.html) as a template. Reduce the `width` of `.box` so you can place more than 2 boxes as colums.